# spider IDE python. Difference in running by pressing F5 and F9?

Tags: python

I have a specific question concerning the python (Python 2.7) IDE Spider (2.3.5.2)

Today I noticed that there is a difference in running my script as a whole, i.e. when I press <kbd>F5</kbd>. 
Or
when I run just a single line or selection, by pressing <kbd>F9</kbd>.

I noticed this difference, when running specific syntax containing `__file__` 
When I would run the script by line (by pressing <kbd>F9</kbd>), I would get the error `NameError: name '__file__' is not defined` 
Whereas if I would run the script as a whole (by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>) I would receive no such error, and was able to retrieve my file name using `__file__`

My question is: What is the difference between running by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> and running by pressing <kbd>F9</kbd>?

Note: there is probably some jargon that I'm missing which would allow me to ask my question better. Please edit the question if needed. I get the feeling I'm dealing with some very basic stuff. If anyone has some good tutorials or documentation, I would love to read it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is normal that you find `__file__` undefined when running by single line because:

> When a module is loaded in Python, `__file__` is set to its name. You
>   can then use that with other functions to find the directory that the
>   file is located in.

There is no loaded module when you run by single line.

Comment: Could you add link of documentation to your answer?