# in spyder IDE, run selection works fine, run file keeps running/ hangs

Tags: console, ipython, spyder, edgar

in Spyder IDE, the run selection command (F9) works fine. the run file command (F5) keeps running for hours, without outputs except

> In [1]: runfile('...\MyFolder\MyScrip.py', wdir='...\MyFolder')

until I restart the kernel.

already seen this questions (same, without useful answers)

- [Spider Run button doesn't behave as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43877759/spider-run-button-doesnt-behave-as-expected)
- [Spyder: different results depending on if I run code with F5 or F9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55952689/spyder-different-results-depending-on-if-i-run-code-with-f5-or-f9)

my script is:

```
import edgar as edg
edg.download_index(r'D:\SEC',2019)
```

where "edgar" is python-edgar (pip).

I used another package, by pip, called edgar, which is always imported as "edgar".

They were installed toghether, so a though about a conflict, and I removed both and reainstalled just python-edgar. Totally useless!

Answer (score 0):

Faced the  similar issue in Spyder IDE (3.3.4.) and Windows10. Took half hour to wait in the first try and returned nothing for waiting hours since the second try.

But everything is just fine now in my case, took just a few seconds to download all files when using PowerShell.

> Python run.py -y 1993