# Spyder: different results depending on if I run code with F5 or F9

Tags: python-3.x, spyder, execute

I've got different results while trying to run the same following code:

```
    import PyPDF2, pdfplumber, re, pandas, sys, os, time, glob
    import numpy as np
    from read_pdf_function import *
    from os import listdir
    from os.path import isfile, join
    from time import gmtime, strftime,localtime
    from multiprocessing import Pool

    path=glob.glob('SFCR\*.pdf') 
    with Pool(8) as p: 
            fPage = p.map(find_data, path) 
    print(fPage)
```

(find_data is a function that I wrote in read_pdf_function, it returns the first page with data of a pdf)

-If I run the file pressing the F5 key, the script returns nothing and just keeps runing.

-If I run selecting the whole code then pressing F9, the script returns the values I'm looking for.

I've never been in front of this case. 
What can be done to let code be executed in both ways?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possibly related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32116528/spider-ide-python-difference-in-running-by-pressing-f5-and-f9

Comment: Hello Hoog, thanks for you answer! I've already read this related post but it stills doesn't help me to get around my problem.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) It probably has to do with your usage of multiprocessing, if you're on Windows. Please update to our latest version and try again.

Comment: Thanks for you answer Carlos! I've updated spyder to the latest version (3.3.4) then restarted computer and I'm still getting this problem. As you said it has something to do with multiprocessing but I don't precisely get it...